# Contar numero de linhas do arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo

Bom dia,essa função  conta o numero de linhas de um arquivo,porém ela tem um probleminha,ela só conta a linha quando acha o \n,por exemplo pra testar ela,eu criava um arquivo de texto,e escrevia uma palavra para vê se tava ok,porem não contava a linha,e depois fui saber que não contava pq eu não tinha dado enter no final da palavra e por isso ela nao achava o \n,alguem poderia dizer outra forma de contar o numero sem ter que me preocupar de dar um enter na palavra?
Código da função:

```
char numerolinhas(){
    char contar;
    int linhas=0;
    FILE *file;

    file=fopen("Frutas forca.txt","r");

    char conta;
    while((conta=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
        if(conta=='\n'){
        linhas++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    return linhas;
```

Answer (score 1):

O teu problema é a definição de "linha".

Normalmente uma linha é definida por "uma sequência de (0 ou mais) caracteres terminada por, e **incluindo**, um *fim-de-linha*".

Nalguns casos também se pode definir por "uma sequência de (0 ou mais) caracteres separados por um *fim-de-linha* (ou EOF) que não pertence à linha".

No primeiro caso o fim-de-linha faz parte da linha, no segundo caso não.

O teu programa usa a primeira definição de linha, mas o ficheiro que usas foi criado com a segunda definição.

Solução 1) altera o ficheiro de modo a satisfazer a definição de linha usada pelo programa

Solução 2) altera o programa de modo a aceitar a segunda definição de linha.

---

Um ficheiro vazio (0 bytes) quantas linhas tem?
definição 1) 0 linhas; definição 2) 1 linha (vazia)

Um ficheiro com um X (1 byte) quantas linhas tem?
definição 1) 0 linhas (1 caracter "solto"); definição 2) 1 linha (com "X")

Um ficheiro com um ENTER (1 byte) quantas linhas tem?
definição 1) 1 linha (vazia, ie apenas com o ENTER); definição 2) 2 linhas

Comment: Obrigado,mas poderia escrever o código da forma que você explicou?não consigo aplicar no código.Com o código vou poder aprender de fato.

Comment: Então, é fácil. Com a definição de linhas que queres usar, basta somar `1` ao número de linhas da outra definição... `return linhas + 1;`

Comment: Creio que só se aplicaria este somar 1 caso o último caractere não seja um '\n'. Ao chegar ao EOF, isto é após o fim do loop, teste se o último caractere lido é ou não um '\n' e some 1 se não for.

Comment: Ah!... e como diz o @anonimo, ainda há uma terceira definição (condicional) possível para linha :)

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões,vou tentar.